# How to exclude numbers in factor program ? AND How to re prompt user until a certain number is entered?

Tags: java

So I am doing this project. And I need to

- Write a program that finds the factors and number of factors for an integer.
- Factors will be listed on 1 line for smallest to largest with a space separating each.
- Continuously accept input until a 0 is entered, which is the sentinel. Do not factor 0.

I got the factoring part. This is the output I am currently getting.

```
Enter an Number
12
The factors are 
1 2 3 4 6 12
```

It stops immediately after giving the factors. I am not sure on how to implement it to re prompt. I have tried loops but its not working. Also,How can I exclude 1 and the entered number.

This is how my output should look. It should stop once 0 is entered.

```
Enter a number: 12
There are 4 factors for the number 12: 2 3 4 6
Enter a number: 25
There are 1 factors for the number 25: 5
Enter a number: 100
There are 7 factors for the number 100: 2 4 5 10 20 25 50
Enter a number: 13
There are 0 factors for the number 13:
Enter a number: 0
```

Here is the code.

```
package com.FactorsProgram;
import jdk.swing.interop.SwingInterOpUtils;
import java.sql.SQLOutput;
import java.util.Scanner;


 //Java Program to print all factors of a number using function

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N;
        Scanner scanner;
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter an Number");
        N = scanner.nextInt();

        // Calling printFactors method to print all
        // factors of N
        printFactors(N);
    }


     //This method prints all factors of N
    public static void printFactors(int N) {
        int i;

         //Check for every number between 1 to N, whether it divides N. If K
         //divides N, it means K is a factor of N
        
        System.out.println("factors for the number " );
        for (i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            
            if (N % i == 0) {

                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I have tried loops but its not working."* - A loop is exactly how one would do this.  What did you try and how did it fail?  The code shown doesn't appear to include any such attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had the right idea with having a loop - you need to loop and check that `n` isn't `0`. E.g.:

```java
System.out.println("Enter an Number");
n = scanner.nextInt();
while (n != 0) {
    // Calling printFactors method to print all
    // factors of N
    printFactors(n);

    System.out.println("Enter an Number");
    n = scanner.nextInt();
}
```